# Question about solved problem

Tags: geometry, roots

I am struggling to understand a step in the accepted solution of 
[How Can One Prove $\cos(\pi/7) + \cos(3 \pi/7) + \cos(5 \pi/7) = 1/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140388/how-can-one-prove-cos-pi-7-cos3-pi-7-cos5-pi-7-1-2).

I have been new to this site, I can not figure out where to ask this question.

> Can someone please enlighten me why $u^5+u^3+u=a$ is equivalent to $ua+1=a$?

With algebra, I just get stuck. I also can't find any property that establishes the equivalence.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can One Prove $\cos(\pi/7) + \cos(3 \pi/7) + \cos(5 \pi/7) = 1/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140388/how-can-one-prove-cos-pi-7-cos3-pi-7-cos5-pi-7-1-2)

Comment: Because $u^6 + u^4 + u^2 + 1 = u^5 + u^3 + u \iff u\cdot(\color{blue}{ u^5+u^3+u})+1=\color{blue}{u^5+u^3+u}\,$ where $\,\color{blue}{u^5+u^3+u}=a\,$.

Answer (score 0):

If you plot the points $(\cos \frac {(2n+1)\pi}7,\sin\frac {(2n+1)\pi}7)$ with $n\in\{0,\cdots, 6\}$ they will form a regular $7-gon.$

If you average these $7$ points together, they will average to the center of the unit circle i.e. $(0,0)$

$\cos \frac {\pi}{7} + \cos \frac {3\pi}{7}+\cos \frac {5\pi}{7}+\cos \frac {7\pi}{7}+\cos \frac {9\pi}{7}+\cos \frac {11\pi}{7}+\cos \frac {13\pi}{7} = 0$

$\cos \frac{\pi}{7} = \cos \frac{13\pi}{7}$ and pair-off the rest.

$2\cos \frac {\pi}{7} + 2\cos \frac {3\pi}{7}+2\cos \frac {5\pi}{7}+\cos \frac {7\pi}{7}= 0\\  
\cos \frac {7\pi}{7} = -1\\
\cos \frac {\pi}{7} + \cos \frac {3\pi}{7}+\cos \frac {5\pi}{7}= \frac 12$

Comment: But i asked why u^5+u^3+u=a is equivalent to ua+1=a? Btw, what does 'gon' mean?

Comment: @CapitalMatters 7-gon was meant to stand for "heptagon", which is a polygon with seven sides.

Comment: In the linked post $u^6 + u^4 + u^2 + 1 = u+u^3 + u^5$  On the LHS factor out a $u$ from the first 3 terms i.e. $u(u^5 + u^3 + u) + 1= u+u^3 + u^5$ Next, Let $a = u + u^3 + u^5.$ Then $ua+1 = a$

Answer (score 0):

$u^5 + u^3 + u = a$ alone does *not* imply $ua + 1 = a$.

But when we are given that $u^6 + u^4 + u^2 + 1 = u^5 + u^3 + u$ we can conclude that:

$(u^5 + u^3 + u)*u + 1 = (u^5 + u^3 + u)$.

For short hand we are *defining* $a$ to be $a:= u^5 + u^3 + u$

and as a result we have $[a]u + 1 = [a]$ where $a$ is shorthand for $u^5 + u^3 + u$.

So $a = u^5 + u^3 + u$ !!!AND!!!! $au + 1 = a$ $\iff u^6 + u^4 + u^2 + 1 = u^5 + u^3 + u$